# Why is Python not printing my code?

Tags: python

I apologize if this is stupid but have been looking for about 30 minutes and cant see what i have done wrong.

```
def biggestnumber( num1, num2 ):
    if num1 > num2:
        print num1, "is greater than", num2
    else:
        print num2, "is greater than", num1

biggestnumber(45, 21)
```

it is complaining that print expected an indented block, but it is indented!

error message:

```
File "main.py", line 3
    print num1, "is greater than", num2
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Did you try to add parenthesis around the content of the print?

Comment: Works fine for me, make sure you're not mixing tabs and spaces in your indentation.

Comment: @Thomas then the error would be `Missing parentheses in call to 'print'` instead of an error regarding indented block

Comment: Works fine for me, too, can you paste the error message?

Comment: error message now in question

Comment: Voting to close this question - the error cannot be reproduced

Comment: what online editor are you guys using/recommend ? im using `http://www.skulpt.org/#`

Comment: This is almost certainly the result of mixing tabs and spaces.  You should always indent either with a tab or with a number of spaces, and never mix them.

Comment: @MarkRansom: A tab is eight spaces under Python 2.  Under Python 3, a tab is a tab, a space is a space, and there is no conversion at all (mixing is illegal).

Comment: You are using Python version 3. So you have to use print(num1, "is greater than", num2)

Comment: @Kevin I just tested in Python 2.7 and you're correct, thanks for that. I'll delete my earlier comment.

Comment: @NguyenSyThanhSon: I don't see any indication from OP that they are using Python 3.  If they were, the error message would be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to add () around the print statement. The code works exactly as you have it above and has been tested. The issue is you are mixing tabs and spaces. If you put () around the print statement as listed above it will actually print them in the console.

```
>>> (45, 'is greater than', 21)

def biggestnumber( num1, num2 ):
    if num1 > num2:
        print num1, "is greater than", num2
    else:
        print num2, "is greater than", num1

biggestnumber(45, 21)
```

your code prints like this:

```
>>> 45 is greater than 21
```

Answer (score -1):

try this on line 3 of your biggestnumber() function:

```
print "%d is greater than %d"%(num1, num2)
```

Answer (score -1):

The tabs or spaces made no difference for me, just putting () around the print function made it work.

```
def biggestnumber(num1, num2):
        if num1 > num2:
            print (num1, "is greater than", num2)
        else:
            print (num2, "is greater than", num1)

biggestnumber(45, 21)
```

Online demo:
https://repl.it/BOkX

On my ide, this error usually meant I had an ascii unprinted character which could be fixed by rewriting the line or showing the unprinted characters with a symbol.

Comment: If it's missing a `(` the error would be `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'` That's not what the OP is having a problem with.

Comment: @Leb I am aware of this however if OP is to try this code I am fairly certain it will work.

Comment: I'm aware that your code works, but your solution is to add `()` which is not the solution. What you did is fixed the indentation, you could add that as the answer. If you take your live demo and take away the `()` which you're claiming is the solution you'll get the same error I provided in my first comment. Not the error the OP got.